# How can I improve/change the shader to be like the image in my message and not as it is in my scene?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, shader

This is what I want to get as blur background image :

[image: The blur background image I want to get]

And this is what I'm getting now and it's not the same blur effect :
It looks like my blue background image is more strecth and blur and not like the image in my first screenshot :

[image: My background image]

This is my shader code :

```
Shader "Tutorial/023_Postprocessing_Blur"{
    //show values to edit in inspector
    Properties{
        [HideInInspector] _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BlurSize("Blur Size", Range(0,0.5)) = 0
        [KeywordEnum(Low, Medium, High)] _Samples("Sample amount", Float) = 0
        [Toggle(GAUSS)] _Gauss("Gaussian Blur", float) = 0
        [PowerSlider(3)]_StandardDeviation("Standard Deviation (Gauss only)", Range(0.00, 0.3)) = 0.02
    }

        SubShader{
            // markers that specify that we don't need culling 
            // or reading/writing to the depth buffer
            Cull Off
            ZWrite Off
            ZTest Always


            //Vertical Blur
            Pass{
                CGPROGRAM
                //include useful shader functions
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                //define vertex and fragment shader
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #pragma multi_compile _SAMPLES_LOW _SAMPLES_MEDIUM _SAMPLES_HIGH
                #pragma shader_feature GAUSS

                //texture and transforms of the texture
                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float _BlurSize;
                float _StandardDeviation;

                #define PI 3.14159265359
                #define E 2.71828182846

            #if _SAMPLES_LOW
                #define SAMPLES 10
            #elif _SAMPLES_MEDIUM
                #define SAMPLES 30
            #else
                #define SAMPLES 100
            #endif

                //the object data that's put into the vertex shader
                struct appdata {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                //the data that's used to generate fragments and can be read by the fragment shader
                struct v2f {
                    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                //the vertex shader
                v2f vert(appdata v) {
                    v2f o;
                    //convert the vertex positions from object space to clip space so they can be rendered
                    o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.uv;
                    return o;
                }

                //the fragment shader
                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_TARGET{
                #if GAUSS
                    //failsafe so we can use turn off the blur by setting the deviation to 0
                    if (_StandardDeviation == 0)
                    return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                #endif
                //init color variable
                float4 col = 0;
            #if GAUSS
                float sum = 0;
            #else
                float sum = SAMPLES;
            #endif
                //iterate over blur samples
                for (float index = 0; index < SAMPLES; index++) {
                    //get the offset of the sample
                    float offset = (index / (SAMPLES - 1) - 0.5) * _BlurSize;
                    //get uv coordinate of sample
                    float2 uv = i.uv + float2(0, offset);
                #if !GAUSS
                    //simply add the color if we don't have a gaussian blur (box)
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
                #else
                    //calculate the result of the gaussian function
                    float stDevSquared = _StandardDeviation * _StandardDeviation;
                    float gauss = (1 / sqrt(2 * PI * stDevSquared)) * pow(E, -((offset * offset) / (2 * stDevSquared)));
                    //add result to sum
                    sum += gauss;
                    //multiply color with influence from gaussian function and add it to sum color
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, uv) * gauss;
                #endif
                }
                //divide the sum of values by the amount of samples
                col = col / sum;
                return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }

            //Horizontal Blur
            Pass{
                CGPROGRAM
                //include useful shader functions
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                #pragma multi_compile _SAMPLES_LOW _SAMPLES_MEDIUM _SAMPLES_HIGH
                #pragma shader_feature GAUSS

                //define vertex and fragment shader
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                //texture and transforms of the texture
                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float _BlurSize;
                float _StandardDeviation;

                #define PI 3.14159265359
                #define E 2.71828182846

            #if _SAMPLES_LOW
                #define SAMPLES 10
            #elif _SAMPLES_MEDIUM
                #define SAMPLES 30
            #else
                #define SAMPLES 100
            #endif

                //the object data that's put into the vertex shader
                struct appdata {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                //the data that's used to generate fragments and can be read by the fragment shader
                struct v2f {
                    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                //the vertex shader
                v2f vert(appdata v) {
                    v2f o;
                    //convert the vertex positions from object space to clip space so they can be rendered
                    o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.uv;
                    return o;
                }

                //the fragment shader
                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_TARGET{
                #if GAUSS
                    //failsafe so we can use turn off the blur by setting the deviation to 0
                    if (_StandardDeviation == 0)
                    return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                #endif
                //calculate aspect ratio
                float invAspect = _ScreenParams.y / _ScreenParams.x;
                //init color variable
                float4 col = 0;
            #if GAUSS
                float sum = 0;
            #else
                float sum = SAMPLES;
            #endif
                //iterate over blur samples
                for (float index = 0; index < SAMPLES; index++) {
                    //get the offset of the sample
                    float offset = (index / (SAMPLES - 1) - 0.5) * _BlurSize * invAspect;
                    //get uv coordinate of sample
                    float2 uv = i.uv + float2(offset, 0);
                #if !GAUSS
                    //simply add the color if we don't have a gaussian blur (box)
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
                #else
                    //calculate the result of the gaussian function
                    float stDevSquared = _StandardDeviation * _StandardDeviation;
                    float gauss = (1 / sqrt(2 * PI * stDevSquared)) * pow(E, -((offset * offset) / (2 * stDevSquared)));
                    //add result to sum
                    sum += gauss;
                    //multiply color with influence from gaussian function and add it to sum color
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, uv) * gauss;
                #endif
                }
                //divide the sum of values by the amount of samples
                col = col / sum;
                return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
        }
}
```

This is the link with the blur image I'm trying to get but he didn't provided the shader code he is using: So I thought maybe there is something I can change/add to my shader code to get the same result as in the link :

https://sharpcoderblog.com/blog/unity-3d-create-main-menu-with-ui-canvas

Comment: See difference between "motion blur" and "Gaussian blur". You seem to have implemented the former, when what you seem to want is the latter.

Comment: On further inspection of the code you've copied and are trying to use, it seems that the shader implements Gaussian, but only if you define the `GAUSS` symbol. Did you do that?

Comment: No I didn't define the GAUSS symbol.

Comment: Well, there you go. That's probably what's wrong.